# Ubuntu 19.04 won't boot without hdmi connected

Tags: 18.04, 19.04, hdmi, monitor

I have installed ubuntu 19.04, and it won't boot without HDMI connected, I have tested Ubuntu 18.04 and it has no problem, so it shouldn't be from bios. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

One possible explanation is that Ubuntu 19.04 is using a different graphics driver that has some problems. In that case, installing another graphics driver can help.

On my laptop I was able to fix a similar problem by doing this, after I had installed 19.04:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I don't have any nvidia graphic card, just intel on board uhd 600

Comment: @Pourya actually I also had a Intel UHD (620 in my case) but installing the nvidia driver seemed to help anyway. :-) I don't know the details of why, but I guess the driver has some basic functionality that is portable and useful also for Intel controllers.

Comment: Ok, I will test. Thanks

Comment: It didn't work, the pc will show a black screen with a blinking dash sign (-), and won't boot.

Comment: @Pourya to get it to at least boot without graphics, so that you can change things like drivers etc, you should be able to boot to runlevel 3. The instructions here should work also for Ubuntu, I think: https://lintut.com/grub2-runlevel-3-howto-change-runlevel-on-grub2/

Comment: So at the GRUB menu you press "e" and then find the line that starts with "linux" and in the end of that line you add a space and a "3" and then you press Ctrl-x and then it boots to runlevel 3 which means that you get a login prompt without any graphics, just a terminal with a login prompt. Does that work? (Then you can login and do something, like removing that driver if it only made things worse.)